# Changing a user's wallpaper in gnome from under another user via the console

Tags: command-line, gnome, desktop-background

There was a need to change the wallpaper centrally, I do it through ansible, respectively, throwing a command from under the right user (manager-1117):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/files/5.jpg "
```

everything works successfully, but at the same time launching it in even to the crown:

```
* * * * * manager-1117 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/files/5.jpg "
```

nothing happens, I also tried the following variations:

```
su manager-1117 -c "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri \"file:///home/files/6.jpg\""
sudo -u manager-1117 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/files/8.jpg"
sudo -u manager-1117 dbus-launch --exit-with-session gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/files/7.jpg"
```

Also, through sticky-bit, I tried stuffing into the sh file, the same result that I missed